# error - Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a web service method that will call SaveItem function as following:

```
public static bool SaveItem(string connection, DataSet dSet)
{
        bool rtnVal = false;
        SqlConnection  conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        conn.Open();
        SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
        SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.Transaction = tran;
        command.CommandTimeout = 320;
        command.CommandText = "SP_UPDATE_ITEM";
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        try
        {
            foreach(System.Data.DataRow dRow in dSet.Tables["Items"].Rows)
            {

                command.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dRow["ItemID"];
                command.Parameters.Add("@ItemName ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dRow["ItemName"];
                command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                command.Parameters.Clear();             
            }
            tran.Commit();
            rtnValue = true;    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tran.Rollback();
            rtnVal = false;
        }
        return rtnVal;
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'

This function will loop through the dataset and update each item one by one, however after certain time it failed and whole transaction get rollback.

Any idea ?

Comment: "after certain time it failed" - what does that mean? Also, the error message in the title has nothing to do with this code...

Comment: explore inner exception.  I belive you are using Web services somewhere  ?

Comment: Let's say if I have 1000 records in the dataset, it will try to update (by calling the store procedure) the first 300 records, after that i will get the error message as per in the title ... I'm lost .. I don't think the error is from the web service caller too (though i could be wrong)